# proguard obfuscation unique method name

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I have some trouble with Proguard I want to obfuscate my java program but I need to have unique methods names when methods have an annotation but Proguard give not unique names when methods have different arguments

Image of what I said before

[image]

Proguard configuration

```
-obfuscationdictionary ./dictionary

-classobfuscationdictionary ./dictionary

-packageobfuscationdictionary ./dictionary

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-dontwarn
-ignorewarnings



# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver

# Also keep - Swing UI L&F. Keep all extensions of javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI,
# along with the special 'createUI' method.
-keep class * extends javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI {
    public static javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI createUI(javax.swing.JComponent);
}

# Keep - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

So I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works about like this:

```
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.SubscribeEvent
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.SubscribeEvent *;
}
```